# Display a list of lists as a tree in Python

Tags: python, list, tree

I would like to define a function to print a list of lists with common components as a tree.

For example,

```
lst = [[1, 2, 'a'], [1, 2, 'b'], [1, 1, 'a'], [1, 1, 'b'], [2, 2, 'a']]
build_tree(lst)
```

should print:

```
1
    1
        a
        b
    2
        b
2
    2
        a
```

I wrote the following code.

```
def build_tree(lst):
    if len(lst[0]) == 1:
        for e in lst:
            return str(e[0])
    current = lst[0][0]
    seen = []
    tree = ''
    for e in lst:
        if e[0] != current:
            tree += str(current)
            tree += build_tree(seen)
            current = e[0]
            seen = []
        seen.append(e[1:])
    return tree
```

But the returned result is nonsense.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I am not new, don't feel like you have to send me the welcome message.

Comment: You might not be new, but you seem to have forgotten what SO is about. Fixing _your_ code  ... of which we see none. What did you code to try to solve this and where is your problem? SO is no coding service....

Comment: I just forgot to include the code. There it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to change your list into a tree strucutre, then loop over that tree to build the string repersentation of your data

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

lst = [[1, 2, 'a'], [1, 2, 'b'], [1, 1, 'a'], [1, 1, 'b'], [2, 2, 'a']]


def make_tree(lst):
    d = tree()    
    for x in lst:
        curr = d
        for item in x:
             curr = curr[item]
    return d

d = make_tree(lst)

def make_strs(d, indent=0):
     strs = []
     for k, v in d.items():
         strs.append('    ' * indent + str(k))
         strs.extend(make_strs(v, indent+1))
     return strs

def print_tree(d):
    print('\n'.join(make_strs(d)))

print_tree(d)
```

prints

```
1
    2
        a
        b
    1
        a
        b
2
    2
        a
```

Comment: It is a good solution indeed (and I upvoted it) but I have no control over the data structure.

Comment: @Blincer You can take the input list and turn it into a `tree` as I have done here.